# Need WPF XML Binding Advice

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, binding

I have a C# WPF program that needs to display GridView and 2D graph data which initially will come from a hardware device. I also want to continuously (or frequently periodic) backup this data to an XML file on disk. What would be the easiest way to implement this in visual studio? Should I create an XML schema first, or use the dataset designer? Should I bother with datasets at all or would it make sense to eliminate them and write my incoming data directly to xml?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

1. Plan a structure of an XML ahead. Create a simple empty file to help you along the way.
2. Create a data serialization provider as well as the interface that it will implement. In your case it will be an XML provider (who knows, you may need to save the data to a database in future. You should plan ahead for that.)
3. Write a custom class that serializes your poco domain objects into an xml using LinqToXML.

Comment: the data won't ever need to be associated with a database. would you still choose this route?

Comment: Using provider pattern is still a best practice since it will allow for easier debugging in future and unit tests. As for everything else - it's a matter of taste. I would use that route in any case, since this is how I work in "current season".